# Errors installing nvidia-driver from buster-backports

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, kernel-modules, backports

I have been using proprietary NVIDIA drivers for my GTX 1650s graphics card with Debian 10. I wish to install nvidia-driver from buster-backports however I am encountering errors.

First, I removed the proprietary drivers with "sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.94.run --uninstall". Rather than rebooting into the console, I then ran "sudo apt -t buster-backports install nvidia-driver". During the installation a notice was printed advising about a mismatch of the kernel module and at the end of the installation, the following was printed:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.12s1avl2-lowlatency (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms (--configure):
 installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:
 nvidia-driver depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 460.73.01-1~bpo10+1) | nvidia-kernel-460.73.01; however:
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-kernel-460.73.01 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-460.73.01 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-kernel-dkms
 nvidia-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone please help? My machine was not rebooted and is still with X running.

Should I reboot into safe mode, remove the modules nvidia,     nvidia_drm and nvidia_modeset with "sudo modprobe -r" and then attempt to install again?

Comment: What does `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/make.log` show?

Comment: Thanks, the first error says:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/iain/kernels/scarlett-gen2-5.15.12s1'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (  \
echo >&2;       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";  \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it
```

Comment: should i do as it says in /home/iain/kernels/scarlett-gen2-5.15.12s1?

Comment: Do you have a complete kernel tree there?

Comment: I built the kernel from this source. It was done to get a troublesome sound card to work.

Comment: OK, so yes, do as it says then.

Comment: It printed: #
# No change to .config
#
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  DESCEND objtool

Comment: I tried to install the backports driver again in any case and it still results in errors

Comment: I notice that I had neglected to build or install the kernel headers. I'm rebuilding now to create the deb file for the headers.

Comment: I built and installed the headers but still can't install the backports nividia-drivers. Results in the same errors. I don't know if i need to reboot.